# Laravel app load without bootstrap 5 on smartphone but work fine on Laptop

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, ovh

I uploaded my Laravel project to OVH server, it works fine on my Laptop but doesn't seem to load Bootstrap on smartphone, anyone had this problem can please help me out please?

[This is on Laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY7DE.png)

[This on my Smartphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ro5La.png)

The css files and js files are compiled with Vite, i tried loading css with asset helper, still the same problem.

this the vite config file

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/sass/app.scss',
                'resources/js/app.js'      
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

and i have this in the head of the app.blade php

```
 @vite(['resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css/dataTable.css', 'public/js/jquery.js', 'public/js/dataTable.js' ,'resources/js/app.js', 'public/css/custom.css', 'public/js/custom.js'])
```

Comment: Please update your question to include `vite.config.js` and provide a [mcve] when asking a question.

Comment: How do you serve your app? Did you deploy it to a virtual server like ec2? Or did you serve it via LAN?

Comment: Did you run via `php artisan serve`? Did you try to access the app using another laptop?

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth I manually deployed it to OVHcloud hosting, run php artisan serve on the server??

Comment: my mistake did not see the part `deployed to OVHCloud` in your question. That's why I asked in my earlier comment.